# Find servernames in a text field, store them in an array, run an sp for each entry

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have records in a Description column that contain the following:

"Server aaa-aaa-aaa was found to be broken and was replaced with server bbb-bbb-bbb at 8pm"

I would like to do something that looks like this:

```
SET @serverArray = empty    
SELECT Description into @serverArray  
WHERE Description like '%-%-%'
FROM Operations

ForEach ROW in @serverArray
{
    sp_HardwareScan (ROW)
}
```

Thus my example would carry out:

```
EXEC sp_HardwareScan (aaa-aaa-aaa)

EXEC sp_HardwareScan (bbb-bbb-bbb)
```

Comment: foreach in TSQL, how quaint.

Comment: Why would anyone want a Sys Admin as a DBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as arrays in SQL Server, and generally you should stop and think about it any time you think about processing things in a loop. That said, it isn't always possible, depending on what you need to do in each iteration of the loop. Here's a simple way to call a stored procedure per row, without creating messy while loop or cursor constructs. This doesn't, however, parse out the part of the description that is just `aaa-aaa-aaa` and `bbb-bbb-bbb`... that wasn't clear initially. Why aren't these stored as separate columns instead of glommed together in a big string? And why are you doing this "hardware scan" from inside SQL Server? Sounds more like a job for PowerShell, C#, etc.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'EXEC sp_HardwareScan ''' + REPLACE(Description,'''','''''') + ''';
'
  FROM dbo.Operations
  WHERE Description LIKE '%-%-%';

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Since I now understand that you need multiple procedure calls per row, how about first creating a split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```

Now you can use the function in an outer apply to get the parts of each string that need to be passed to the stored procedure.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
DECLARE @x TABLE(Description VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @x VALUES('Server c-4-5h was offline & replaced with R2-D2-C3P0 at 5AM'),
('Server aaa-aaa-aaa was broken & replaced with server bbb-bbb-bbb at 8pm');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'EXEC sp_HardwareScan ''' + REPLACE(Value, '''', '''''') + ''';
'
FROM @x AS x OUTER APPLY dbo.SplitString(REPLACE(x.Description,' ',';'), ';') AS y
WHERE y.Value LIKE '%-%-%';

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Result:

```
EXEC sp_HardwareScan 'c-4-5h';
EXEC sp_HardwareScan 'R2-D2-C3P0';
EXEC sp_HardwareScan 'aaa-aaa-aaa';
EXEC sp_HardwareScan 'bbb-bbb-bbb';
```

Just replace `@x` with `dbo.Operations` to test against your real table ([always specify schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)).

More on split functions, why (and proof that) while loops and recursive CTEs don't scale, and better alternatives, if splitting strings coming from the application layer:

- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)
- [Comparing string splitting / concatenation methods](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat)
- [Processing a list of integers : my approach](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/01/processing-a-list-of-integers-my-approach)
- [Splitting a list of integers : another roundup](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup)
- [More on splitting lists : custom delimiters, preventing duplicates, and maintaining order](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/06/more-on-splitting-lists-custom-delimiters-preventing-duplicates-and-maintaining-order)
- [Removing Duplicates from Strings in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4140/removing-duplicates-from-strings-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

On SQL Server 2016 or above, though, you should look at [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql):

- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : STRING_SPLIT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split)
- [STRING_SPLIT() in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [STRING_SPLIT() in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #2](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-2)
- [SQL Server v.Next : STRING_AGG() performance](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/12/sql-performance/sql-server-v-next-string_agg-performance)
- [Solve old problems with SQL Server’s new STRING_AGG and STRING_SPLIT functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5275/solve-old-problems-with-sql-servers-new-stringagg-and-stringsplit-functions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Also, [**STOP** using the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: @DeluctantRBA did you [clicky the linky](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)?

Comment: I did now :) I wonder if a prefix that starts with an 'a' would run faster than 'proc.  A single column per word in this field isn't possible for this system, they want the whole mess.

Comment: @DeluctantRBA Prefix isn't going to matter (ask yourself what purpose the prefix serves anyway), unless the prefix is `sp_`.

Comment: Many thanks Mr. Bertrand, I follow most of what you did except the "'" on line 11 by itself, could you please explain it's purpose?

Comment: To put a carriage return so it has each command on its own line. Makes it a lot easier to read than `command;command;command;command;`